# AS3 constructor has no method with the same name as the class

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns

I was reading [ActionScript 3.0 Abstract Factory Design Pattern: Multiple Products and Factories](http://www.as3dp.com/2009/01/25/actionscript-30-abstract-factory-design-pattern-multiple-products-and-factories/), and I have the following,

```
private var busFactory:AbFactory;
busFactory=new BusinessFactory();
```

Both in **BusinessFactory.as** and in **AbFactory.as** there is no *method* with the *same name* as the *class*, only `createProductA` and `createProductB`. So, how could `busFactory` call the *constructor* with `new BusinessFactory` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default constructors for both `AbFactory` and `BusinessFactory` (which the article shows inherits from `AbFactory`) are created by the compiler.

If you start to pass arguments to the `BusinessFactory()` constructor, the compiler will complain about an unexpected argument count. That's when you need to write the constructor yourself. But passing nothing means the default can be used.

Comment: but won't it run the code automatically, right ? If I got a class drawPlease where I got only a drawNow method, must I have to call the method on it explicitly ? example 1: myDrawPleaseObject.drawNow()
----------------
but If both has the same name(class and method), when I run myDrawPleaseObject = new drawPlease() will it be calling the method like in example 1?

Answer (score 0):

Also the reason that you could set a AbFactory to a BusinessFactory means that they share the same heritage.